# How to reduce Docker image size of Nuxt app?

Tags: docker, vue.js, minify, nuxt.js

I am using docker to deploy my nuxt app. However my docker image size is 260MB. Is it too big for a docker image. I've used node alpine to reduce docker size. 
This is the dockerfile.

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app


# copy the app, note .dockerignore
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
# set app port
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

# start the app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I want to have an docker image of size <100MB. Is there any more configuration needed for nuxt app or docker commands to be added?

Comment: Where is the actual space being taken up now?  Except that the `npm install` line should be one line earlier this looks like a very typical Node Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do multi stage docker build.
Idea is, you use one image for build, and then just copy plain javascript files to alphine image.
Check good example here - https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2871

Also, as JMLizano mentioned, at run image you can install packages without dev ones - 
`npm install --production`
(example above just copy *all* build modules to run image)

Comment: Here is example I used nginx as base image -
https://gitlab.com/gintsgints/vue-fullstack/blob/master/packages/client/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Nuxt, but some things you can try are:

- Group the two `COPY` statements, seems like it should be enough with `COPY . .`
- Group the two `RUN` statements (Ex. `RUN npm install && npm build`)
- Avoid installing dev packages -> Use the `--production` flag   of [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#description).

The two first will reduce the amount in layers in the image, but do not expect a huge size reduction. The third one is where you can save more space (in case you have a lot of dev packages).

Comment: ok. tried grouping the statements together but getting same result. my package is not very high, in fact checked my production distribution folder size is only 12 MB.

Comment: Hmm then the image size shouldn't be that big. Maybe you can check your `.dockerignore` to be sure that you are not including anything besides the code (and any required files) in the `COPY . .` instruction.